# Clusters of Residuals in Diagnostics Plot

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, clustering, residuals, diagnostic

I have a 1338x7 data set on which I am attempting to run a regression. The goal is to predict insurance charges based on the following predictors: age (cont), sex (0/1), BMI (cont), children (discrete), smoker (0/1), region (northeast, southeast, northwest, southwest).

After EDA, I had a hypothesis that charges = age + BMI + smoker + BMI*smoker. First, I fit the full model with no interaction terms and the following was output:

[image: Regression Output]

The fit doesn't look too bad, in my opinion.  However, in looking at the diagnostic plots, I saw some strange things. I understand the Q-Q suggests non-normality in the residuals (correct?). I am more interested in understanding this: What do the clusters of residuals in the "Residuals vs Fitted" plot indicate? How do I move forward? Obviously, this is a pattern, but it is not easily fixed such as using some sort of data transformation. Thank you!

[image: Diagnostics]

** EDIT** 
In my EDA, this plot indicated to me that there may be four subgroups: "high-BMI smokers", "high-BMI non-smokers", "low-BMI smokers", and low-BMI non-smokers".  How would this be incorporated into regression?

[image: Smokers vs BMI vs age vs Charges]